# Not able to load chart using amcharts when making an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I am using amcharts to make a pie chart. On a button click i am making an AJAX request to get data from mysql. And I am getting the data in JSON format.

Once I receive the JSON array I pass the data to amcharts but it is not showing. But if I am redirecting to new jsp page then the chart is showing up.

My HTML code is:

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="shift" value="shift analysis" onclick="shift(a,b,c,d)">
<div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 640px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", {
       "type": "pie",
       "theme": "light",
      
       "valueField": "f2",
       "titleField": "t",
        "balloon":{
        "fixedPosition":true
       },
       "export": {
         "enabled": true
       }
     } );
       
    
    
    
    function shift(a,b,c,d)
     {
       var ajax_req =new XMLHttpRequest();
       var method = "GET";
       var url ="endpoint";
       var asynchronous = true;
       
       ajax_req.open(method, url, asynchronous);
       ajax_req.send();
       
       ajax_req.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
               {
           // document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = this.responseText;
           
          var result= this.responseText;
           alert(result);
                chart.dataProvider =result;
          chart.validateNow();
    
               }
         }
      }
```

for better understanding this is the output of my AJAX request:
result: [{"t":"01:11","f2":340},{"t":"01:11","f2":335},{"t":"01:09","f2":334}]

Comment: Are you sure that your shift() get called when you click. `onclick="shift(a,b,c,d)">` I think that a,b,c,d may causing since they are undeclared

Comment: yeah.. those are just aliases. Not the actual parameters which i am passing. More important is i am getting the response as JSON array like this  [{"t":"01:11","f2":340},{"t":"01:11","f2":335},{"t":"01:09","f2":334}]. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you're returning a JSON response in your `XMLHttpRequest` callback, `responseText` is a *string type* (you can confirm this by doing `typeof this.responseText` in your debugger). You need to manually convert your response to a JavaScript array before assigning it to the dataProvider. You can do this using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

`chart.dataProvider = JSON.parse(result);`

Also make sure you call [`validateData`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) to update the chart. [`validateNow`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateNow) by default skips data validation if you omit the first parameter and is typically used to update visual properties.

[Demo using jsfiddle echo](http://jsfiddle.net/g0eo4v3k/18/)

Comment: I just noticed you're using `validateNow`. Switch to `validateData` or use `validateNow(true)`. See my updated response for a demo.